# problemas con GPS para una app android

Tags: android

En una actividad tengo un boton que automaticamente me devuelve la calle, la ciudad y el pais en el que me encuentro.
Esto sucede siempre y cuando tengo la ubicacion activada en el movil. Si estando dentro de esa actividad la desactivo, logicamente no me detecta la posicion.Tengo que reactivar la ubicacion, y esperar un rato para que me de la posicion otra vez.

Viendo ademas la app de Google Maps, me he fijado que si intentas acceder a tu ubicacion y esta desactivada,primero te pide activarla, y despues te la devuelve al momento, sin tener que esperar.

Hay alguna manera de que al pulsar el boton me solicite activar la posicion y me la de al momento?

Os paso la actividad al completo con la que de momento, si tengo la ubi activada me devuelve al momento los datos.

```
package com.example.oftecnica2.agendajose;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Address;
import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.os.Vibrator;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

public class CrearReunion extends AppCompatActivity implements LocationListener {

    TextView txtreunion;
    ArrayList<Reunion> reuniones = new ArrayList();
    ImageView imgaceptar;
    ImageView imgcancelar;
    EditText txtgps;
    String direccion = "/";
    boolean unavez = false;
    private LocationManager locationManager;
    private String provider;
    int pulsacion = 0;
    Vibrator vibrator;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_crear_reunion);
        txtreunion = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtreunion);
        txtgps = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtgps);
        setTitle("NUEVA REUNION");
        imgaceptar = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgaceptar);
        imgcancelar = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgcancelar);
       vibrator = (Vibrator) getSystemService(VIBRATOR_SERVICE);


        imgcancelar.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                switch (motionEvent.getAction()) {

                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

                        imgcancelar.setImageResource(R.drawable.cancel2);
                        vibrator.vibrate(30);

                        break;


                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        imgcancelar.setImageResource(R.drawable.cancel);
                        cancelar();
                        break;


                }
                return true;
            }
        });


        imgaceptar.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                switch (motionEvent.getAction()) {

                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

                        imgaceptar.setImageResource(R.drawable.ok2);
                        vibrator.vibrate(30);

                        break;


                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        imgaceptar.setImageResource(R.drawable.ok);
                        aceptar();
                        break;


                }
                return true;
            }
        });


    }


    public void aceptar() {


        SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("MisPreferencias", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        int numeroreunion = prefs.getInt("numeroreunion", 0);
        numeroreunion = numeroreunion + 1;


        //creo la reunion
        int id = numeroreunion;
        String nombre = txtreunion.getText().toString();


        String cadena = "";
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

        String dia = String.valueOf(calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
        String mes = String.valueOf(calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1);
        String ano = String.valueOf(String.valueOf(calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR)));
        String hora = String.valueOf(calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR));
        String minutos = String.valueOf(calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
        String segundos = String.valueOf(calendar.get(Calendar.SECOND));
        String direccionFinal =txtgps.getText().toString();


        if (mes.length() == 1) {
            mes = "0" + mes;
        }
        if (dia.length() == 1) {
            dia = "0" + dia;
        }
        if (hora.length() == 1) {
            hora = "0" + hora;
        }
        if (minutos.length() == 1) {
            minutos = "0" + minutos;
        }
        if (segundos.length() == 1) {
            segundos = "0" + segundos;
        }


        Date ahora = new Date();
        String fecha = dia + "/" + mes + "/" + ano;
        String horaFinal = hora + ":" + minutos;


        Reunion reunion = new Reunion(id, nombre, fecha, horaFinal,direccionFinal);


        //cargo las otras reuniones si las hay
        File tarjeta = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        File archivo = new File(tarjeta.getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + "Reuniones", "reuniones.txt");

        try {
            ObjectInputStream entrada = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(archivo));
            reuniones = (ArrayList) entrada.readObject();
            entrada.close();

            System.out.println("tras leer");
            System.out.println(reuniones.size());
            reuniones.add(reunion);
        } catch (Exception e) {


        }

        //creo la estructura de carpetas

        File carpetaPrincipal = new File(tarjeta.getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + "Reuniones" + File.separator + String.valueOf(id));
        File carpetaFotos = new File(carpetaPrincipal.getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + "fotos");
        File notas = new File(carpetaPrincipal.getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + "notas.txt");
        File datos = new File(carpetaPrincipal.getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + "datos.txt");


        try {
            carpetaPrincipal.mkdir();
            carpetaFotos.mkdir();
            notas.createNewFile();
            datos.createNewFile();
            //creo el molde de cliente en el fichero
            ObjectOutputStream entrada = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(datos));
            Cliente cliente = new Cliente("", "", "", "");
            entrada.writeObject(cliente);
            entrada.close();
            //creo el molde


            ObjectOutputStream entrada2 = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(notas));
            ArrayList<Nota> notas2 = new ArrayList();
            entrada2.writeObject(notas2);
            entrada2.close();


        } catch (Exception e) {

        }


        //guardo y acabo
        try {

            File archivo2 = new File(tarjeta.getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + "Reuniones", "reuniones.txt");
            ObjectOutputStream salida = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(archivo2));
            salida.writeObject(reuniones);
            salida.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
        }


        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        editor.putInt("numeroreunion", id);
        editor.commit();
        setResult(RESULT_OK);
        finish();


    }

    public void cancelar() {
        setResult(RESULT_CANCELED);
        finish();
    }

    public void busqueda(View view) {
            vibrator.vibrate(30);
            txtgps.setText("");
            locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
            Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
            provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                return;
            }
            Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
            if (location != null) {
                onLocationChanged(location);
            }

            locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
            txtgps.setText(direccion);
            unavez=false;
            direccion="/";


    }


    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return;
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return;
        }
        locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
        List<Address> addresses = null;
                try {
            addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude(), 1);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (addresses != null && unavez == false) {
            Address address = addresses.get(0);
            for (int i = 0; i <= address.getMaxAddressLineIndex(); i++) {
                direccion += address.getAddressLine(i);
                direccion += "/";
            }
            unavez = true;
        }
    }

        @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {

    }
}
```

Comment: Es decir solo quieres obtener una vez la posición?

Comment: Please, follow this link, you can try this solution https://elandroidelibre.elespanol.com/2018/01/trucos-para-mejorar-el-gps-de-tu-movil.html

Answer (score 1):

Esto lo he sacado de [este post de stack overflow en inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5481695/how-to-enable-gps-in-android-coding) es para activar el gps mediante código. Espero que te sirva

```
private void toggleGPS(boolean enable) {
String provider = Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(), 
    Settings.Secure.LOCATION_PROVIDERS_ALLOWED);

if(provider.contains("gps") == enable) {
    return; // the GPS is already in the requested state
}

final Intent poke = new Intent();
poke.setClassName("com.android.settings", 
    "com.android.settings.widget.SettingsAppWidgetProvider");
poke.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_ALTERNATIVE);
poke.setData(Uri.parse("3"));
context.sendBroadcast(poke);
}
```

Comment: fijate los comentarios de esa publicación --> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5481695/how-to-enable-gps-in-android-coding/5481752#comment6409803_5481752

Comment: Gracias a Alberto y Mariano, finalmente para activar la ubicacion es esta parte de codigo:  final Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS); intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT); intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK|Intent.FLAG_AC‌​TIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF‌​_NEEDED); intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.android.settings", "com.android.settings.Settings$LocationSettingsActivity")); mContext.startActivity(intent);

Comment: El problema sigue siendo que tarda demasiado en devolverme la ubicacion tras la activacion del gps....

Comment: @SergioCv Obtener una ubicación en frío lleva tiempo. De hecho, cuanto más tiempo lo tengas encendido, más confiable será

Comment: Gracias de nuevo Mariano!, entonces intentar conseguir la fluidez de localizacion desde la activacion que tiene Google Maps es tarea casi imposible?

Comment: Creo que para eso google tambien te ubica mediante las redes moviles @SergioCv

Comment: vaya que interesante!! bueno intentare buscar algun ejemplo, si encontrais alguno y os apetece compartirlo estare muy agradecido!!

Comment: Tengo entendido que si usas las google play services con la nueva api de localización se obtiene al momento https://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html